# Why the multiplication between two Markov Chain transition matrices is commutaive?

Tags: matrices, markov-chains

Can anyone give some intuitive proof the following proposition?

For any two Markov Chain transition matrices $A$, $B$ ($n$ by $n$ matrix that has every row sum to $1$), we have $A * B = B * A$.

Comment: Can you add some links to make this more accessible to readers? Imagine someone who doesn't know what a Markov Chain is.

Comment: @Mason It is stated in the question exactly what a transition matrix is, what more context is needed?

Comment: @Math1000 

Why people study Markov models, what's a Markov chain?. All of this could be included with a [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain). I think that a tiny bit of critique is appropriate for a new contributor and was prompted to do so because I was going through a review cue.
I am not sure whether the question is particularly interesting but certainly the question is not interesting without the knowledge that this fact might be useful when studying a meaningful phenomenon or a mathematics people take seriously. 

So a link offers context.

Comment: I believe more context is necessary in terms of the poster's understanding of and attempt at solving the question, hence the close vote, but the question itself is self-contained.

Comment: @Mason Does every single question about Markov chains need a history of the subject? I'm all for context, but what you're asking for is ridiculous. People that somehow stumbled on this question without knowing what a Markov chain is can just click on the tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's false. For example,
$$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$
but
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}.$$
The zero-one example is just particularly easy to compute with, but $AB$ won't be equal to $BA$ for almost any pair of transition matrices $A,B$.